# React Native pulls the same data twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

There are two different arrays in the database, but it prints the information in duplicate when displaying it. I have put the screenshots of the database, screen and output below

At the top, I will have only 1 graph and the information from Top3Data in this database will be, and at the bottom, the information I named data will come.

My problem is that the data I pull from the database comes in twos.

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import 
{ View,
   Text,
   SafeAreaView,
   StyleSheet,
   Dimensions ,
  } from 'react-native';
import {
  ProgressChart,
  
} from "react-native-chart-kit";
import PagerView from 'react-native-pager-view';
import auth, { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
   
style={
  marginVertical: 8,
  borderRadius: 16
};


export default class level extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list:[],
      
    };
    
  }

  componentDidMount(){

    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const db = firebase.database();

const ref = db.ref('LevelData/'+`${user}`);

    ref.on('value',(snapshot)=>{

      var li=[];

        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
          
          li.push({
            key:child.key,
            data:snapshot.val().data,
            Top3Data:snapshot.val().Top3Data,
            
            //Top3Data:snapshot
            //Top3Data:child.val().Top3Data,
            
          })

        }
        
    )
    
      this.setState({list:li})
     console.log(li)
    
    })
    
  }

  renderLevel(){
    var lis=[] 
     lis=this.state.list
     
    return lis.map((key) => 
    
    <View style={styles.botChartsView} >
    <ProgressChart
      
    data={key.data}
    width={120}
    height={180}
    strokeWidth={16}
    radius={32}
    hideLegend={false}
    strokeWidth={20}
    chartConfig={{
      backgroundColor: "#e26a00",
      backgroundGradientFrom: "#fb8c00",
      backgroundGradientTo: "#ffa726",
      decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
      color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
      labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
style: {
borderRadius: 16
},
propsForDots: {
r: "6",
strokeWidth: "2",
stroke: "#ffa726"
}
}}
/></View>);
    
  }

  renderLevel1(){
    var lis=[] 
     lis=this.state.list
    return lis.map((key) => 
    <ProgressChart
              data={key.Top3Data}
              width={320}
              height={200}
              strokeWidth={16}
              radius={32}
              hideLegend={false}
              strokeWidth={20}
              chartConfig={{
                backgroundColor: "#e26a00",
                backgroundGradientFrom: "#fb8c00",
                backgroundGradientTo: "#ffa726",
                decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
                color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
                labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
    style: {
      borderRadius: 16
    },
    propsForDots: {
      r: "6",
      strokeWidth: "2",
      stroke: "#ffa726"
    }
  }}
/>);
    
  }
  
  render() {

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
       
          <View  style={styles.topChart}>
            <View style={styles.topThird}>
              <Text style={styles.topThirdtext}>EN İYİ 3</Text>
            </View>
              {this.renderLevel1()}
      </View>

      <PagerView style={styles.botChart}  initialPage={0}>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}} key='0'>
        {this.renderLevel()}
        </View>
      </PagerView>
      
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

This firebase database

[image]

This console output

[image]

This app screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8sWi.png)

Comment: When dealing with arrays of components, you should provide [a `key` property](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) so that React can handle duplicate children efficiently.

Comment: Please add what your desired outcome is to your question. This could be a mocked up image and/or description of the graphs. Is one graph meant to be the top 3 and another the "data" graph?